# html/java user submitted changes appear live for everyone

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My website has a comment box that when submitted appears above what they wrote, this works great. The problem is that I would like the section where everyone who uses my website and submits their comments appears right after each other for example:

user 1 submits: Hey everyone

user 2 submits: my name is

user 3 submits: David

it appears as:

hey everyone my name is David

and everyone, who visits the site, sees the comments left by other users all in the same sentence. The changes are not saved and appear to everyone only to themselves and when they refresh it all disappears.

Comment: You can't do this just with client-side javascript. There are two possibilities: using AJAX with php or using NodeJs for a server-side application

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a database of some sort for your website. where users can send the comments there and every time you refresh the page, your website will call the data/comments for it to show in your web page